# Importing JSON file and discover key names with OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to bulk import a JSON file with exercise data from Fitbit.  Before I insert the data into a table, I want to find all the distinct key names used across the entire file.

**TL;DR:  How do I "collapse" the `OUTER APPLY` results below into a single set of distinct keys?**

```
declare
    @json nvarchar(max) = '[
    {
        "logId": 5687739287,
        "activityName": "Walk",
        "activityTypeId": 90013,
        "averageHeartRate": 100,
        "calories": 140,
        "duration": 1178000,
        "activeDuration": 1178000,
        "steps": 1584,
        "logType": "auto_detected",
        "manualValuesSpecified": {
            "calories": false,
            "distance": false,
            "steps": false
        },
        "lastModified": "01/21/17 15:14:05",
        "startTime": "01/20/17 20:07:43",
        "originalStartTime": "01/20/17 20:07:43",
        "originalDuration": 1178000,
        "elevationGain": 0.0,
        "hasGps": false,
        "shouldFetchDetails": false,
        "hasActiveZoneMinutes": false
    },
    {
        "logId": 8704352278,
        "activityName": "Bike",
        "activityTypeId": 90001,
        "averageHeartRate": 147,
        "calories": 742,
        "distance": 10.955718,
        "distanceUnit": "Mile",
        "duration": 3823000,
        "activeDuration": 3579000,
        "source": {
            "type": "tracker",
            "name": "Charge 2",
            "id": "86599831",
            "url": "https://www.fitbit.com/",
            "trackerFeatures": [
                "HEARTRATE",
                "GPS",
                "DISTANCE",
                "CALORIES",
                "SPEED",
                "ELEVATION"
            ]
        },
        "logType": "tracker",
        "manualValuesSpecified": {
            "calories": false,
            "distance": false,
            "steps": false
        },
        "tcxLink": "REDACTED",
        "speed": 11.020001341156748,
        "lastModified": "07/10/17 01:05:32",
        "startTime": "07/09/17 23:53:39",
        "originalStartTime": "07/09/17 23:53:39",
        "originalDuration": 3823000,
        "elevationGain": 497.998688,
        "hasGps": true,
        "shouldFetchDetails": true,
        "hasActiveZoneMinutes": false
    }
]';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#exercise') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #exercise


SELECT activity.*
FROM OPENJSON (@json)
WITH(
    logId bigint
    ,activityName varchar(max)
    ,activityTypeId int
    ,source nvarchar(max) as JSON
    ,averageHeartRate int
    /*
        ????
        not all keys are known
        ????
    */
) AS activity



/*
    I cannot take credit for this trick.
    It shows me all the keys, BUT
    it's for EACH record, and there are hundreds of records!

    How do I collapse these results to see a single set of distinct keys?

*/

SELECT L1.[key], L2.[key], L2.[value]
FROM openjson(@json,'$') AS L1
OUTER APPLY openjson(L1.[value]) AS L2
```

The source file is relatively consistent, but not all entries will have the same keys as shown in the image below.  The "Bike" activity has more content than the "Walk" activity, `source: {}`, `speed`, `tcxLink`, `distanceUnit`, etc. etc.

[image]

Although I can target an grab data with `FROM OPENJSON`, I simply don't know what keys to expect throughout the entire file.

```
...
FROM OPENJSON (@json)
WITH(
    logId bigint
    ,activityName varchar(max)
    ,activityTypeId int
    ,source nvarchar(max) as JSON
    ,averageHeartRate int
    /*
        ????
        not all keys are known
        ????
    */
)
```

[image]

So.... this `OUTER APPLY` is helpful, but is there anyway to "collapse" it so that I see a single set of all used keys?  (not repeated for every single activity)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DISTINCT keyword to condense the results:

```
SELECT distinct L2.[key] 
FROM openjson(@json,'$') AS L1
OUTER APPLY openjson(L1.[value]) AS L2
```

Comment: That did it!!  I had tried using `DISTINCT`, but I didn't remove the other columns `L1.[key], L2.[value]`